# Loop using onchange and getelementbyID not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown

I'm trying to disable the top dropdown option if ever there's an answer on the 2nd row up to the 355 rows but I'm having a hard time with the codes because it only runs on the row that you've clicked and won't check the other row if there's an answer.

Here's my code on the javascript

I copy the part of the code for the HTML

```js
jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").change(function() {

  if (jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").val() != "") {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 355; i++) {
      jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~x" + i + "']").prop('disabled', true)
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 355; j++) {
      jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~x" + j + "']").prop('disabled', false)
    }
  }
});
for (var i = 1; i <= 355; i++) {
  jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~x" + i + "']").click(function() {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 355; j++) {
      var e = document.getElementById("QR~QID7~x" + j);
      var selectedDropdown = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      if (selectedDropdown != "") {
        jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").prop('disabled', true)
      } else {
        jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").prop('disabled', false)
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~2" id="QID7-2-label"><span>All countries</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~2" id="QR~QID7~2" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.2.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x1" id="QID7-x1-label"><span>All Countries</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x1" id="QR~QID7~x1" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x1.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x2" id="QID7-x2-label"><span>Asia Pacific (All)</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x2" id="QR~QID7~x2" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x2.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x3" id="QID7-x3-label"><span>Australia</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x3" id="QR~QID7~x3" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x3.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x4" id="QID7-x4-label"><span>Bangladesh</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x4" id="QR~QID7~x4" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x4.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x5" id="QID7-x5-label"><span>Brunei</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x5" id="QR~QID7~x5" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x5.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm not sure if this can help but this code will be run in a platform called "Qualtrics"

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you also using vanilla JS DOM methods like `getElementById`?

Comment: FYI, `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `e.value`. The value of a dropdown is the same as the value of its selected option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop keeps running after it disables the top dropdown, and re-enables it if any of the other dropdowns has no value. You should break out of the loop once you disable the dropdown.

You can also simplify the code by giving all the `QR~QID7~x#` elements a unique class. Then you can select them all with a single selector. You can use `.each()` to loop over them until you find one that has a value.

```js
jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").change(function() {
  jQuery(".QR-QID7-x").prop('disabled', this.value != "");
});

$(".QR-QID7-x").change(function() {
  jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").prop('disabled', false);
  jQuery(".QR-QID7-x").each(function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      jQuery("[id='QR~QID7~2']").prop('disabled', true)
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~2" id="QID7-2-label"><span>All countries</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~2" id="QR~QID7~2" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.2.Selected" class="QWatchTimer">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x1" id="QID7-x1-label"><span>All Countries</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x1" id="QR~QID7~x1" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x1.Selected" class="QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x2" id="QID7-x2-label"><span>Asia Pacific (All)</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x2" id="QR~QID7~x2" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x2.Selected" class="QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x3" id="QID7-x3-label"><span>Australia</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x3" id="QR~QID7~x3" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x3.Selected" class="QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow   ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x4" id="QID7-x4-label"><span>Bangladesh</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x4" id="QR~QID7~x4" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x4.Selected" class="QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ChoiceRow ReadableAlt  ">
    <th scope="row" class="c1" id="header~QID7~1">
      <span class="LabelWrapper"> <label for="QR~QID7~x5" id="QID7-x5-label"><span>Brunei</span></label>
      </span>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th class="c2 BorderColor">&nbsp;</th>
    <td class="c3 BorderColor">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="c4 last">
      <select name="QR~QID7~x5" id="QR~QID7~x5" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.x5.Selected" class="QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x">
        <option aria-label="Blank" value=""></option>
        <option value="1" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.1.Display">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.2.Display">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.3.Display">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.4.Display">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5" data-runtime-html="runtime.Answers.5.Display">Option 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hello Barmar,

Thank you for your answer. I tried it but didn't work. I won't be able to edit the classname because it is the default built html for Qualtrics and I can only get their ID.

I also try to change the classname for the code to run but it also didn't work.

Here's the code I added.
document.getElementByClass("QWatchTimer").className = "QWatchTimer QR-QID7-x";

On my previous code, I followed your advice and added a break; on the loop but it also didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: QWatchTimer includes other dropdowns, so you don't want to do that. I changed the code to use an attribute prefix selector.